# Migrating salted sha512 passwords from symfony 2 to firebase authentication

Tags: firebase

I am trying to migrate users (including passwords) from an old symfony 2 application to firebase authentication (or google identity platform).

In the symfony2 application the passwords of the users are hashed using sha512 with a salt.  I already found that users can be imported using their password and hash in the documentation of firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users). However it seems like the sha512 hashing that is used by firebase is not the same as was used by symfony.

For the old symfony project the following configuration is used:

```yaml
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
```

By looking into the source I found that symfony given a salt and a password symfony will produce the hash like this: (in python code)

```py
def get_hash(salt, password):
    hash = password.encode('utf-8')
    salted = hash + salt
    hash = hashlib.sha512(salted).digest()
    for i in range(1, 5000):
        # symfony keeps adding salted for every iteration, this is something firebase does not it seems
        hash = hashlib.sha512(hash + salted).digest()
    return base64.b64encode(hash).decode('utf-8')
```

However this code does not allow me to login when i import it like in the code below. It however does produce the same hash as I have in my database of the symfony2 application:

```py
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()
salt = '{test}'.encode('utf-8')
hash = get_hash(salt=salt, password='xyz')
print('calculated hash', base64.b64encode(hash))
users = [
    auth.ImportUserRecord(
        uid='foobar',
        email='foo@bar.com',
        password_hash=hash,
        password_salt=salt
    )
]
hash_alg = auth.UserImportHash.sha512(rounds=5000)
try:
    result = auth.import_users(users, hash_alg=hash_alg)
    for err in result.errors:
        print('Failed to import user:', err.reason)
except exceptions.FirebaseError as error:
    print('Error importing users:', error)
```

I can however login with the password when i use the following fuction.

```py
def get_hash(salt, password):
    hash = password.encode('utf-8')
    salted = salt + hash
    hash = hashlib.sha512(salted).digest()
    for i in range(1, 5000):
        hash = hashlib.sha512(hash).digest()
    return hash
```

I have already found a way to change the order of adding the salt but i can find no way to hash like this in firebase `hash = hashlib.sha512(hash + salted).digest()`.

Now it seems like there is no way to migrate my password to firebase as the implementation of symfony is a bit different from the one used by firebase. Does anyone know a way to make sure I can still import my current hashes? This would be great.

If not, what would be alternative work arounds?

- Is it possible to let firebase do a request to my own endpoint to verify password.
- Another way would be to try to catch the signin process and send it to my own endpoint first, set the password in the background and then send the request to firebase?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what your client application is using, so I'm just going to assume it's a web application that will use the Firebase Web SDK.

To use this solution, you'll need to migrate the Symfony user data to Firestore under a private `_migratedSymfonyUsers` collection, where each document is the email of that user.

On the client, the process will be:

1. Collect email and password from the user
2. Attempt to sign in to Firebase with that email and password combination
3. If that failed, invoke a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) with that email and password combination.
4. If function returned a success message (see below), reattempt signing in the user with the given email and password
5. Handle success/errors as appropriate

On the client, this would look like:

```js
const legacySignIn = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('legacySignIn');

async function doSignIn(email, password) {
  try {
    return await firebase.auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  } catch (fbError) {
    if (fbError.code !== "auth/user-not-found")
      return Promise.reject(fbError);
  }

  // if here, attempt legacy sign in
  const response = await legacySignIn({ email, password });
  
  // if here, migrated successfully
  return firebase.auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}

// usage:
doSignIn(email, password)
  .then(() => console.log('successfully logged in/migrated'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('failed to log in', err));
```

In the Callable Cloud Function:

1. (optional) Assert that the request is coming from your application with [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check)
2. Assert email and password were provided and throw error if not.
3. Assert that the email given exists in your migrated users and throw an error if not.
4. If in migrated users, hash the password and compare against the stored hash.
5. Throw an error if hashes don't match.
6. If hashes match, create a new Firebase user with that email and password combination
7. Once created, delete the migrated hash and return success message to the caller

On the server, this would look like:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

function symfonyHash(pwd, salt) {
  // TODO: Hash function
  return /* calculatedHash */;
}

exports.legacySignIn = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (context.app == undefined) { // OPTIONAL
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'failed-precondition',
        'The function must be called from an App Check verified app.');
  }

  if (!data.email || !data.password) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'invalid-argument',
        'An email-password combination is required');
  }

  if (data.email.indexOf("/") > -1) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'invalid-argument',
        'Email contains forbidden character "/"');
  }

  const migratedUserSnapshot = await admin.firestore()
    .doc(`_migratedSymfonyUsers/${data.email}`);

  if (!migratedUserSnapshot.exists) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'not-found',
        'No user matching that email address was found');
  }

  const storedHash = migratedUserSnapshot.get("hash");
  const calculatedHash = symfonyHash(password, salt);

  if (storedHash !== calculatedHash) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'permission-denied',
        'Given credential combination doesn\'t match');
  }
 
  // if here, stored and calculated hashes match, migrate user

  // get migrated user data
  const { displayName, roles } = migratedUserSnapshot.data();

  // create the user based on migrated data
  const newUser = await admin.auth().createUser({
    email,
    password,
    ...(displayName ? { displayName } : {})
  });

  if (roles) { // <- OPTIONAL
    const roleMap = {
      "symfonyRole": "tokenRole",
      "USERS_ADMIN": "isAdmin",
      // ...
    }
    
    const newUserRoles = [];
    roles.forEach(symfonyRole => {
      if (roleMap[symfonyRole]) {
        newUserRoles.push(roleMap[symfonyRole]);
      }
    });

    if (newUserRoles.length > 0) {
      // migrate roles to user's token
      await setCustomUserClaims(
        newUser.uid,
        newUserRoles.reduce((acc, r) => { ...acc, [r]: true }, {})
      );
    }
  }

  // remove the old user data now that we're done with it.
  await hashSnapshot.ref.delete();

  // return success to client
  return { success: true };
});
```